# No idea why a function ran out of gas

Tags: solidity, blockchain, remix

Hello guys I work on remix so my gas limit is set on 3000000.
When I deploy and call the delMember function, it reverts with the "The transaction ran out of gas. Please increase the Gas Limit." and I really don't understand why.
I tried to increase the gas limit but it has no effects.

My contract :

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity 0.8.13;

import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract Whitelist is Ownable{
    mapping(address => bool) public whitelist;
    address[] private Members;

    event MemberAdded(address indexed _addressAdded);

    constructor(){
        whitelist[msg.sender] = true;
        Members.push(msg.sender);
        emit MemberAdded(msg.sender);
    }

    function addMember(address _address)external onlyOwner{
        require(!whitelist[_address], "Address is already registered");
        whitelist[_address] = true;
        Members.push(_address);
        emit MemberAdded(_address);
    }

    function getMember(address _address)external view returns(bool){
        if(whitelist[_address]){
            return true;
        }
            return false;
    }

    function getMembers()external view returns(address[] memory){
        address[] memory tmpMembers = new address[](Members.length);
        for(uint i; i < Members.length; i++){
            tmpMembers[i] = Members[i];
        }
        return tmpMembers;
    }

    function delMember(address _address)external onlyOwner{
        require(whitelist[_address], "Member not registered");
        whitelist[_address] = false ;
        //uint index;
        /*
        for(uint i; i < Members.length; i++){
            if(Members[i] == _address){
               index = i;
            }
        }
        */
        //Members.pop();
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a problem with gas limit on Remix IDE. You can see the issue at this link: https://github.com/ethereum/remix-project/issues/2310.  Try to inject your smart contract into web3 on any testnet and try it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer !
I commented the pop part, the error is just on the whitlist[_address] = false, if I set it on true there is no error